# LinqToXml: parsing to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following xml:

```
<Places Count='50'>
<Place ID='1' Row='1' Place='1' Type='1' Fragment='0'></Place>
<Place ID='2' Row='1' Place='2' Type='1' Fragment='0'></Place>
<Place ID='3' Row='1' Place='3' Type='2' Fragment='0'></Place>
<Place ID='4' Row='1' Place='4' Type='2' Fragment='0'></Place>
<Place ID='5' Row='1' Place='5' Type='2' Fragment='0'></Place>
//other tags
</Places>
```

I want to get `Dictionary<int, int>` with the following content:

```
1,2  // 0 element in the Dictionary (type =1; count = 2)
2,3; // 1 element in the Dictionary (type =2; count = 3)
```

The first parameter is `Type` in xml, the second parameter is count of this types.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand how to convent it to Dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ to XML combined with LINQ to Objects makes this very simple:

```
var dictionary = doc.Descendants("Place")
                    .GroupBy(x => (int) x.Attribute("Type"))
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

It's not as efficient as it could be, but I'd stick with this implementation until I found it became a problem.

Note that talking about the "0 element" in a dictionary is misleading - dictionaries have no reliable ordering: you shouldn't assume that if you iterate over the key/value pairs you'll see them in any particular order.

Answer (score 1):

Query syntax

```
 var dict = (from place in root.Descendants("Place")
       group place by (int)place.Attribute("Type") into g
        select g).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Count());
```